# How to access a structure in a variable whose name is in a string

Tags: c, variables, structure

```
struct Rigs {
    char  ip[16];
    char  outlet[3];
};

int main {
    char user_choice[4];
    scanf("%s", user_choice);

    char target[7];
    sprintf(target, "Rig%s", user_choice);

    struct Rigs Rig201;
    strcpy(Rig201.ip, "192.168.1.98");
    strcpy(Rig201.outlet, "11");

    printf("Target's Address Found At: %s\n Rig's Outlet is # %s\n", 
    target.ip, target.outlet);

    return 0
}
```

So if the user chose 201, the string Rig201 is generated, i then want to call Rig201.ip etc.

How do you call what i am trying to do?

I am having a lot of trouble finding information on this, as this is normally very straightforward on the higher level languages i am more accustomed to.

I figure this would be a lot easier using a switch, but there should still be a way to make this work!

Comment: You can make an array `struct Rigs Rig[500];` and use `Rig[atoi(user_choice)].ip`. Do not forget to add sanity checks.

Comment: C doesn't have variable-variables, you need to create a lookup table.

Comment: What languages are you used to? You can't do what you want in Python or Javascript. In PHP you need a variable variable: `$$target['ip']`

Comment: What names the application use doesn't necessarily have a direct connection with variables. Variables are used to make the program understandable for the programmer, not the user. In this case it sounds as if you need to allocate a large array of "Rigs", default initialize them, then let the user pick and configure a specific one.

Comment: Is that style struct declaration even legal in C?  I could swear gcc didn’t think so last time I checked

Comment: Thanks guys. I managed to get it done this way. Now i think even more strongly that SWitch should be use to hard coding the values.
https://i.imgur.com/gpzGBUG.png